# WifiManager preventing loop code from executing

Tags: c, server, esp32

A little help please.
This wifi manager has options for what to do at first run if no stored wifi credentials are found.
The AP_NONE option far as I can tell should allow code in the loop to continue running while AP portal is open but it doesn't.
Please let me know what I'm missing.
thanks.
Sketch and links to header and source files:
https://github.com/smurf0969/WiFiConnect/blob/master/src/WiFiConnect.h
https://github.com/smurf0969/WiFiConnect/blob/master/src/WiFiConnect.cpp

```
#include "WiFiConnect.h" 

#include <WiFiClient.h>                      
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266  
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#else  
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#endif

WiFiConnect wc;

// For internet connection
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

const int pin18=18;

void configModeCallback(WiFiConnect *mWiFiConnect) {
  Serial.println("Entering Access Point");
}


void startWiFi(boolean showParams = false) {
 
  wc.setDebug(true);
  
  /* Set our callbacks */
  wc.setAPCallback(configModeCallback);

  //wc.resetSettings(); //helper to remove the stored wifi connection, comment out after first upload and re upload

    /*
       AP_NONE = Continue executing code
       AP_LOOP = Trap in a continuous loop - Device is useless
       AP_RESET = Restart the chip
       AP_WAIT  = Trap in a continuous loop with captive portal until we have a working WiFi connection
    */
    if (!wc.autoConnect()) { // try to connect to wifi
      /* We could also use button etc. to trigger the portal on demand within main loop */
        wc.startConfigurationPortal(AP_NONE);//if not connected show the configuration portal
    }
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.println("....");
  Serial.println("....");
  delay (5000);
  startWiFi();
  pinMode(pin18, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  
digitalWrite(pin18, HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(pin18, LOW);
delay(500);
    
    
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("Testing with connection to internet...");

    http.begin(client, "http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/");

    int httpCode = http.GET();
    
    if (httpCode > 0) 
    {    
      
      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
      
      // file found at server
      if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) 
      {
          Serial.println("HTTP_CODE_OK");
      }
      
    } else {
       Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    
    http.end();  
  
    // Wifi Dies? Start Portal Again
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      if (!wc.autoConnect()) wc.startConfigurationPortal(AP_NONE);
    }
  
  delay (20000);
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `startWiFi` in a loop though. Are you supposed to?

Comment: @Irelia  I'm not sure I see why I should. Should I be.  I don't see how that would help flashing the led in the loop which currently is not being executed.

Comment: so you're implying `startWifi` blocks and never returns?

Comment: yes. I saw some code  references to "apcontinue" in the source files but is honestly above my head.

Comment: Yes, strange. According to the source code if AP_NONE is provided, it should just return. Are you sure that's where you're stuck? Can you do some sort of print after you call wc.startConfigurationPortal(AP_NONE); To see if the function actually returns or not?

Comment: Ok I'll check on that today. Thanks.